# Nodejs rest api & database recommendations

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js, nosql

I am working on building a social app and let's assume the app has the following features:

1. User feed
2. Friend request, Connections.
3. Likes
4. Comments

For the same, I am building a REST API using nodejs and my experience with nodejs is limited. I have spent alot of time researching and I found information in bits and pieces. I am looking forward to hear some suggestions from the experts :)

1. I am planning to use NoSQL graph database(Neo4j, OrientDB). Is this a good choice. or are their better options or should I go with a relational database like mysql?
2. For CRUD operations, I was thinking sailjs. (I was planning on using yeoman, but there are no generators for Sails yet). Thoughts/Recommendations?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: may i ask what you like about using sails?

Comment: Mongodb might be worth a look? http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: @dandavis - connect to any database (I know they officially support local disk, redis, my sql and few other). support for websockets and there is a passport based authentication generator for use with sails. :)

Comment: @Magrangs - I have researched a lot on mongodb and people have expressed their frustration very soon after adapting mongo.

Comment: @AbhilashShamsunder I am not too familiar with it myself but what kind of frustrations are they experiencing? (for future reference).

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge fan of the MEAN Stack. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) for the database, [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) as a Node framework, [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) for the front-end, and [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) on the server. With that said, the applications I have built work well with MongoDB's NoSQL structure. For a social network a relational database may make much more sense and save you some headaches down the road. [Here](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) is a thorough article explaining why.

Comment: I am a huge fan of MEAN stack. But based on my research mongodb has its own set of limitations as you mentioned.

Comment: Anytime the term 'social' is introduced I shy away from Mongo. Friends, likes, comments, etc. are possible to model with Mongo, but inefficient and cumbersome as said social network grows. Still a huge advocate of Node on the server and Angular as a front-end framework though.

Comment: I agree. Angular front end is my favorite as well. I am planning to use ionic (dependency on angular) framework to build my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code.

Server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql   = require("mysql");
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
var rest = require("./REST.js");
var app  = express();

function REST(){
    var self = this;
    self.connect_to_mysql();
}

REST.prototype.connect_to_mysql = function() {
    var self = this;
    var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'restful_api_demo',
        debug    :  false
    });
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if(err) {
          self.stop(err);
        } else {
          self.configureExpress(connection);
        }
    });
}

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection) {
      var self = this;
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
      app.use(bodyParser.json());
      var router = express.Router();
      app.use('/api', router);
      var rest_router = new rest(router,connection);
      self.start_server();
}

REST.prototype.start_server = function() {
      app.listen(3000,function(){
          console.log("All right ! I am alive at Port 3000.");
      });
}

REST.prototype.stop = function(err) {
    console.log("ISSUE WITH MYSQL \n" + err);
    process.exit(1);
}

new REST(); // Instantiate clas
```

Here is REST.js

```
function REST_ROUTER(router,connection) {
    var self = this;
    self.handle_routes(router,connection);
}

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handle_routes = function(router,connection) {
    router.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.json({"Message" : "Hello World !"});
    })
}

module.exports = REST_ROUTER;
```

Link : http://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/restful-api-node-and-express-4/

Answer (score 0):

sailsjs with couchdb and angular js would be my recommendation.you can refer [couchdb vs mongodb](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-vs-couchdb.html)
also refer [this](https://github.com/pillarjs/node-frameworks#included-features)
to see the advantages & features of sails. 
You can use `nano` along with `couchdb-lucene` to get the most out of couch db.